# How I can set the background image to table cells that have a colspan?

Tags: html, css

I use css to set the background to the cell but it does not apply to the whole cell.

I am trying to set the background image to First and last `<TR>`, but it's showing like this.

I am trying to apply `.first` class property for first and last `<tr>`. What should I do so it applies to TR?

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">

 .excel{
         background:url(smallimage/excel.jpg);
          background-size:24px 24px;
          background-repeat:no-repeat;
          position: relative;
           margin:3px;
           left: 2px;
            top: 1px;
        }


        td.yellostar{
        background-image: url(smallimage/yellowstar.jpg);  /* forward slash for the path */
        width: 20px; /* use you own image size; */
        height: 20px; /* use you own image size; */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: top;
        } 
        .first{
        background-image:url(smallimage/trbackgr.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table width="95%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="first">
        <th colspan="2" class="first">chapter #|chapter Name</th>
        <th>Linkage</th>
        <th>project<br/>count</th>
        <th>Task<br>count</th>
        <th>issues<br> Open/All</th>
        <th>Action</th>

      </tr>
        <tr >
        <td>05</td>
        <td><div class="excel" > &nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<u>Chapter 5:Data of Information</div></td>
        <td class="yellostar" ></td>
        <td><p align="center">3</p></td>
        <td><p align="center">21</p>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>06</td>
        <td><div class="excel">&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<u>Chapter 6:Data Tabels and Amortization Tabels</div></td>
        <td class="yellostar">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07</td>
        <td><div class="excel" >&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<u>Chapter 7:Data consolidation,Links and Formula Auditing</div></td>
        <td class="yellostar">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08</td>
        <td><div class="excel" >&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<u></td>
        <td class="yellostar">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>09</td>
        <td><div class="excel" >&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<u></div></td>
        <td class="yellostar">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><div class="excel" >&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<u></div></td>
        <td class="yellostar">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="first">


        <td colspan="7" class="first" >&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Looks good to me, [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/2zj5A/), try checking the url of the image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pseudoclasses `:first-child` and `:last-child` .
Look at my example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vs9NK/)

But `:last-child` is not cross-browser, fixes will be needed for IE.

And you have an error in specifying the reference image for background [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp).

Comment: as per you suggest i use it and its working.But can you tell me when am using dot(.)class to apply backgroung image to<tr> its not applying to whole tr its showing to some part in tr?????

Comment: Everything is working with (.)class too. Just you have properly registered the path to the image. http://jsfiddle.net/dAmYc/